# A prefix notation calculator that asks about everything step by step

Tags: python, python-2.x, calculator

I made a prefix notation calculator.

Prefix notation, aka Polish notation, is a form of notation for logic, arithmetic and algebra, like infix and postfix (reverse Polish) notation.

The expression '+ 3 4' in prefix notation is as valid as '3 + 4' in infix notation, as well as '3 4 +' in postfix notation.

The calculator asks for one value per step, and asks about everything step by step.

```
"""
Pfxcalc
Programmed by zyabin101
This code is hereby released into the public domain
"""

import ast

def lit_input(prompt):
    """
    Safely evaluate input. Only returns the following Python literal
    structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and 'None'.

    Raises ValueError for malformed strings.
    """
    return ast.literal_eval(raw_input(prompt))

def lorr_input(prompt, result):
    inputted = raw_input(prompt)
    return result if inputted == "result" else ast.literal_eval(inputted)

# Initialization
x = None

# Print welcome message
print "Welcome to Pfxcalc. Type 'help' for more information."

# Main program loop
while True:
    # Get user input
    cmd = raw_input(">> ")
    # Process input
    if cmd == "quit":
        break
    elif cmd == "result":
        print x
    elif cmd == "help":
        helpmsg = """
        Pfxcalc is a prefix notation calculator.
        Prefix notation, aka Polish notation, is a form of notation for logic,
        arithmetic and algebra, like infix and postfix (reverse Polish)
        notation.

        The expression '+ 3 4' in prefix notation is as valid as '3 + 4' in
        infix notation, as well as '3 4 +' in postfix notation.

        Every computation starts with entering a command and the result is
        printed *and* saved in a variable that can be recalled by entering
        'result'. The variable can even be used as an argument for functions,
        using the same command.

        List of commands:
        quit - self explanatory
        result - recall the result variable
        help - print this message
        + - add two numbers or sequences
        - - subtract two numbers
        * - multiply two numbers, or a sequence by a number
        / - divide two numbers
        """
        print helpmsg
    elif cmd == "+":
        x = (lorr_input("Left side addend? ", x) +
             lorr_input("Right side addend? ", x))
        print x # Implicitly output result
    elif cmd == "-":
        x = lorr_input("Minuend? ", x) - lorr_input("Subtrahend? ", x)
        print x # Implicitly output result
    elif cmd == "*":
        x = (lorr_input("Left side factor? ", x) *
             lorr_input("Right side factor? ", x))
        print x # Implicitly output result
    elif cmd == "/":
        x = lorr_input("Dividend? ", x) / lorr_input("Divisor? ", x)
        print x # Implicitly output result
    else:
        print "Unrecognized command."
```

I'm interested in code style and problems the code has. What can be fixed here?

Comment: Why not just `print """...."""` instead of `print helpmsg`? It's less assignment, and probably more efficient.

Comment: Most if not all single line comments seem superfluous.

Comment: I assume this is python2.7, because no print parantheses?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Correct.

Comment: The `lit_input()` function is probably unnecessary, because it is defined but never used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Use a shebang at the beginning

This is something like `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, and helps interpreters know how to run it.

#### Remove some of the unnecessary comments

Comments are good. Excessive comments are just hard to read.

e.g.

```
elif cmd == "+":
    x = (lorr_input("Left side addend? ", x) +
         lorr_input("Right side addend? ", x))
    print x # Implicitly output result
```

Turn that into:

```
elif cmd == "+":
    x = (lorr_input("Left side addend? ", x) +
         lorr_input("Right side addend? ", x))
    print x
```

And:

```
# Get user input
cmd = raw_input(">> ")
# Process input
if cmd == "quit":
    ....
```

Into:

```
cmd = raw_input(">> ")
# Process user input
if cmd == "quit":
    ....
```

#### Empty lines for readability

Using the previous example:

```
cmd = raw_input(">> ")
# Process user input
if cmd == "quit":
    ....
```

Into:

```
cmd = raw_input(">> ")

# Process user input
if cmd == "quit":
    ....
```

#### `if __name__ == "__main__"` check

This just checks if you are running this directly, or from a module import/something else.

Maybe put the while loop into a function called `start()` and use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

#### Don't assign unnecessary variables

The `helpmsg` var is pretty much useless, just print the plain string.

#### The `lit_input` function is not used

Either use it, or remove it. Maybe make a variation of the docstring for the `lorr_input`?

#### Other notes:

- Nice job with the ast safe eval, but a method that doesn't involve eval would also be nice. This is a lot of work, probably unnecessary.
- I would set `x` to `0` at the beginning, but that's personal preference.
- I'm not sure, but you appear to have limited to 87 chars per line (or under). That is a PEP guideline, good job.

Comment: Good job! Have your `25` rep, which is `0.225` of my rep (c:).

Comment: @zyabin101 think it's 15, but welcome. You should wait a bit though, give other people a chance to answer.

Comment: 1) It *is* 25 (10 for upvote, 15 for accept). 2) Got it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please do not use `#!/usr/bin/env python` as a shebang. Default Python versions varies across distributions and environments (e.g. Ubuntu/Debian defaults to Python 2.7, Arch Linux defaults to Python 3.x -- [PEP394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) only states that distros *should* point `python` to 2.x), so try to be as precise as possible.

Comment: @ElementW okay, will add to the post.